# Angular - MatTable with Sticky Header and horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, angular

Im having problem merging Sticky Column with horizontal scrolling.

Here you can find and example (the example is Angular 8 but im using Angular 10).

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-u3st54-bqq6wk?file=app%2Ftable-sticky-header-example.html

The base example has sticky headers so if you scroll the **entire** page, headers will be fixed in the top and the rows will scroll behind them.
If you use the horizontal **page** scroll, the headers remains sticky.

[image]

Unfortunally I cant use "page horizontal scroll" but I need a container with an inner scroll.
In the example remove "-fake" from container class.
As you can see, an inner horizontal scroll will appear but the header will be not sticky.

[image]

Is there a way to keep both behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

you have to determine the height of your div for sticky to start working. When scrolling the screen, it does not work, so that it is available, you need to fix it in the body

```
.app-table-wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 400px; //for example
}
```